# Regex replace words starting with 'car' and leaving original word

Tags: sql-server, regex, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I am building a SQL server full text index for a website about, let's say, '`cars`'.

Currently that doesn't work very well since a lot of words in the content start with `car`. If a user searches by the term `keys` the full text index won't match with `carkeys`.

I am thinking of replacing every word that starts with `car` by the word without `car` while leaving the original word.

`Blue carkeys` should be `blue keys carkeys`. Can anyone come up with a regex replace to do so?

Or does anyone know a trick in SQL server to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is a thesaurus (I would use the term "synonym list", but that is the term used for SQL Server.

You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx).

A thesaurus would let you specify that "carkeys" is really equivalent to "car keys".

This let's you do what you want without changing the original data.

Comment: @PeterdeBruijn . . . The question is not tagged with SQL Azure.